# Will the ethereum blockchain have a problem with the timestamp in 2038?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, timestamp

I am reading that [Ethereum EVM run over 32bits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49628/wouldnt-a-64bit-based-evm-be-more-efficient-on-the-ethereum-ecosystem) systems

In base to this information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Will the ethereum blockchain have a problem with the timestamp in 2038?

Comment: EVM don’t handle time, cause timestamps come from the outside and are usually stored in a 256bit unsigned interger. probably Someone with more knowledge can confirm that in an answer

Comment: I didn't say Ethereum is 32 bits system. I said it is a 32 **bytes** one, it is 8 times bigger!

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use an integer on a system where the size of the integer is larger than the system's word size, you explicity use a fixed-width integer.

This allows you to use, for example, 64-bit integers on 32-bit systems by explicitly using `uint64` rather than `uint`, `big.Int`, etc. (depending on language).

To cut a long story short, there was a bug in the Geth client a couple of years ago, whereby Geth's timestamp implementation didn't match that of other clients (Parity?).

Issue [#19372](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/19372) was raised to ensure all Geth's timestamp use was set to use 64-bit integers (I believe in some cases it was using `big.Int`, which is platform dependent).

So the 2038 problem shouldn't be a problem.